# Compaq Presario SR1033WM Specs

Tags: motherboard

I recently bought an old Compaq Presario SR1033WM not realizing what a dog it is. I'd like to save what I can by replacing the motherboard and/or CPU, but I haven't been able for find any specs outside of it MIGHT be a mATX form factor. Can anyone clue me in on what I would need to look for in a replacement CPU or motherboard upgrade in terms of form factor, power requirements, connectors, and whatever. I would greatly appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: this thing is so old you probably won't get much done on the cheap

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Answer (score 1):

Given what I found researching that model of computer [here](http://www.computer-specifications.com/specifications/Compaq-PresarioSR1033WM-Specs.html), you would simply be better off purchasing a new computer.

First off, if you replace the motherboard, you're essentially buying a new computer anyway.  This would require new RAM and CPU, only being able to salvage some other basic hardware (video card, hard drive, and the like).  The case, unless you like the style of it, wouldn't be worth reusing. You would be limited in what you could fit in there, as well as having difficulty getting it in there.

Second, just replacing the CPU would still limit you to the era of technology that produced the motherboard.  There are likely faster processors, but not by much, and certainly not as fast as processors are today.  Next you would be limited on how much memory you could use; according to [this](https://www.cnet.com/products/compaq-presario-sr1303wm-sempron-3000-plus-2-ghz-monitor-none-series/specs/), it has a memory cap of **1GB**.  Windows 7 can run on 512MB, but most applications today balk at anything less than 2GB.

If it is possible to return the computer you just bought, I recommend doing so.  You would be spending too much money trying to make that thing run any faster, and it probably wouldn't do so.

Comment: I realize that I'm not saving anything.  My end purpose is to build a home cloud server, and this looked like a good starting point to hack around as it has almost every type of drive, reader. and io I've ever heard of and a very roomy case to hold several hard drives.  Just doesn't seem it going to work out.